# Write java array to file.txt in one line

Tags: java, arrays, file, printwriter

What should I change in my code to write my array into text file in a single line instead of a different line per vale of the array?

```
PrintWriter zapis = new PrintWriter("wyniki.txt"); 
for (int g=1; g<801; g++)
{
    zapis.println(g+":"+wynik[g]+" ");
}
zapis.close();
```

Comment: Well what does `PrintWriter.println` do? Compare that with what you want it to do, and look for similar-sounding methods that don't do the bit you don't want...

Answer (score 3):

As [`the documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.String-) states, `println` "Prints a String and then terminates the line."

If you don't want to terminate the line, use [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print-java.lang.String-) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line inside for loop like this :

```
zapis.print(g+":"+wynik[g]+" ");
```